# Scala & Kafka: Getting the producer and consumer offset difference and log it

Tags: beginner, scala, apache-kafka

I'm looking to compare `kafka's` `producer` and `consumer` `offsets`, get the delta of that and sum it per topic. The code iterates through each topic & partition -- each topic has many partitions. Each `partition` has an `offset` value.

I'm looping thrice on `offsets`:

1. Get `TopicPartition` & `offset`
2. Get `TopicPartition` & `OffsetAndMetadata`
3. Get the delta between the producer & consumer

This is my first attempt to code in Scala with Kafka, so I am still finding my bearings with it. It would be very helpful if anyone could advise on bad practices or things which I could do to make the code cleaner.

```
   override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    event.progress.sources
      // Ignoring sqs / jms sources their offsets
      .filter(source => source.description.toLowerCase().contains("kafka"))
      // ex offset :
      //    "endOffset" : {
      //      "rcs-enriched-event" : {
      //        "8" : 31376,
      //        "11" : 39114,
      //        "2" : 39376,
      //      } ...
      .foreach(source => {

        /// Map[Topic,Map[Partition, CurrentOffset]]
        val jsonOffsets = objectMapper.readValue(source.endOffset, classOf[Map[String, Map[String, Int]]])
        jsonOffsets.keys.filter(key => topics.contains(key))
          .foreach(topic => {
            val offsets: Map[String, Int] = jsonOffsets(topic)
            val consumedPartitions = new ListBuffer[TopicPartition]()
            val topicOffsetList = new ListBuffer[Int]()

            val mapTopicPartitionOffset = offsets
              .keys
              .map(partition => {
                val tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition.toInt)
                val offset = offsets(partition).toLong
                consumedPartitions += tp
                (tp -> offset)
              })
              .toMap

            val mapTopicPartition = offsets
              .keys
              .map(partition => {
                val tp = new TopicPartition(topic, partition.toInt)
                val oam = new OffsetAndMetadata(offsets(partition).toLong)
                (tp -> oam)
              })
              .toMap

            try {
              val kafkaPartitionOffset = kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(consumedPartitions.asJava)

              for((topicPartition,offset) <- mapTopicPartitionOffset){

                val bbCurrentOffset =  offset

                // latest offset
                val partitionLatestOffset = kafkaPartitionOffset.get(topicPartition)

                // Partition offset delta
                val delta = partitionLatestOffset - bbCurrentOffset

                topicOffsetList += delta.abs
              }
            } catch {
              case e: Exception => {
                log.error(s"${consumerGroupId} Could not get Kafka offset", e)
              }
            }

            try {
              kafkaConsumer.commitSync(mapTopicPartition.asJava)
            } catch {
              case e: Exception => log.error(s"${consumerGroupId} Could not commit offset", e)
            }

            //log.info have the group id (unique id), the topic, cumulative consumer lag delta
            log.info("consumerGroupId: " + consumerGroupId + " topic: " + topic + " lagDeltaSum: " + topicOffsetList.sum)
          })

      })
  }
```